# navigation drawer hidden in my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a big problem with my fragments
In the first fragment(List2) (navigation drawer) I have a listview. But in the User fragment the navigation drawer doesn't appear Can you help me please
Account--> List2 --> User
Account.java

```
public class Account extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
.........................
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new List1()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new List2()).commit();
        } 
}
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

List2.java

```
    public class List2 extends Fragment implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
..........
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), User.class);
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String tid = map.get("name").toString();
                intent.putExtra("nom", tid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

User.java

```
public class User extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
..............

}
}
```

But the classe User seems never used. Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean with: "the second fragment doesn't open very well", the code seems right, i dont know if your JSON decode is right, but i recomend you to debug your showEmployee method and if possible use some sniffer like wireshark to see if the messages sent and recevied are all right.

Comment: @user2542813 thanks sir, only the editTextId is filled and the others data aren't returned: the editTextName, editTextPassword and editTextEmail were empty

Comment: The The navigation drawer is hidden

Comment: i think thats because your query, maybe you should put the $nom variable inside the qutoes: '$nom'

Comment: @user2542813 yeeees it works now :) thanks but  the navigation drawer is still hidden

Comment: edit your question and post what you have done already to create the navigationDrawer

Comment: thanks post edited :)

Comment: So the Drawer are ok, the problem is with the Fragment User, you are calling him through an intent, what seems very wrong as you can read here: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/fragments.html , a fragment must be hosted by an activity, if you want to start the User through List2, you should use the Account as an interface between them, so the Account should start the fragment User properly.

Comment: @user2542813 thanks to your follow up but what did you mean with: "if you want to start the User through List2, you should use the Account as an interface between them" How can I do this?

Comment: when i say "through", this was a mistake, sorry, but i mean "from", and when i say interface i mean like a bridge, from List2 you call, for example: `Account.startUserFragment()`, and the Account will start the User fragment.